# Pass context of calling activity to called activity in android

Tags: android, android-context

I want to pass context of calling activity to called activity so that I can access the spinner present in calling activity
Please help.

Comment: You really can't.  There's no promise the calling activity is even in your app, so they prevent that on purpose.  Even if you do something hack to get at it, it won't work the way you think-  that other activity has been stopped and its ui will not update.  The closest way to do this is to return the new settings as a result when you finish and update the spinner in its owning activity

Comment: I am calling finish() in the called activity and it goes back to the original activity.How can I detect that my original activity is now at the front so that I can update my spinner at that moment.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but that is not possible.

Comment: Can't I use Parceable.

Comment: @ArunimChopra: No. First, you cannot implement `Parcelable` on `Activity`, because you did not write `Activity`. Second, passing a `Parcelable` extra makes a copy of the `Parcelable` object; the recipient gets that copy. Hence, you would not be able to "access the spinner present in calling activity", because you would be working with a copy.

Answer (score 1):

Finally!! I have solved the problem by using startActivityForResult() and getActivityResult() methods.
Thank u.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at PendingIntent. From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html):

> A description of an Intent and target action to perform with it. Instances of this class are created with getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int), getActivities(Context, int, Intent[], int), getBroadcast(Context, int, Intent, int), and getService(Context, int, Intent, int); the returned object can be handed to other applications so that they can perform the action you described on your behalf at a later time.
>     **By giving a PendingIntent to another application, you are granting
>   it the right to perform the operation you have specified as if the
>   other application was yourself (with the same permissions and
>   identity).** As such, you should be careful about how you build the
>   PendingIntent: almost always, for example, the base Intent you supply
>   should have the component name explicitly set to one of your own
>   components, to ensure it is ultimately sent there and nowhere else.